# matrix algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

For every $ n> 2, n\epsilon \mathbb{N}$ let A,B,C,D be matices $ A,B,C,D\epsilon M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ AC-BD=I_{n}$ and $AD+BC=0_{n} $. Prove that:

a) $CA-DB=I_{n}$ and $DA+CB=0_{n}$

b)$ det(AC)\geq 0 $.

My postgraduate degree professor gave us this question. For a) i did the following
$$ AC-BD=I_{n} \Leftrightarrow \\
\sum_{s=i}^{n}a_{is}c_{sj}-b_{is}d_{sj}=0 \forall i\neq j \text{ and } \sum_{s=i}^{n}a_{is}c_{sj}-b_{is}d_{sj}=1 \text{ if } i=j \Leftrightarrow \\\sum_{s=i}^{n}c_{sj}a_{is}-d_{sj}b_{sj}=0 \forall i\neq j \text{ and } \sum_{s=i}^{n}c_{sj}a_{is}-d_{sj}b_{is}=1 \text{ if } i=j \Leftrightarrow
\\ CA-DB=I_{n} \text{ and } 
AD+BC=0_{n} \Leftrightarrow \\
\sum_{s=1}^{n}a_{is}d_{sj}+b_{is}c_{sj}=0 \text{ for } s=1,...,n \Leftrightarrow \\
\sum_{s=1}^{n}d_{sj}a_{sj}+c_{sj}b_{sj}=0 \text{ for } s=1,...,n \Leftrightarrow  \\
DA+CB=0_{n}
$$
and  but it seems like something is missing.
For b i thought of using $det(AC)=det(A)\cdot det(B)$ but either than this i am lost. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Helen For part a), the easiest approach is to use matrices with complex numbers. Using the information given, verify that we have
$$
(A + Bi)(C + Di) = I,
$$
where $i^2 = -1$. Thus, we have $(C + Di) = (A + Bi)^{-1}$, so we also have
$$
(C + Di)(A + Bi) = I \implies\\
(CA - DB) + (DA + CB)i = I + 0i \implies\\
\begin{cases}
CA - DB = I,\\
DA + CB = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer to avoid complex numbers, you can note that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{A & -B\\ B & A}, \quad \pmatrix{C & -D\\ D & C}
$$
must be inverses and proceed in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Do you have any hints about b)?

Answer (score 1):

for b) because $AD+BC=0_{n}$ we get $det(AC+iBC)=det(AC-iAD)$ so $detC=det[(C+iD)(A+iB)C]=det(C+iD)det(AC+iBC)=det(C+iD)det(AC-iAD)=det[(C+iD)A(C-iD)]=detA|det(C+iD)|^{2}$ so $detAC=(detA)^{2}|det(C+iD)|^{2}\geq 0$